# Swiper and Jquery : Going to specific slide from side panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, swiper.js

I have this jquery page where I have used Swiper library to show my contents by sliding vertically. I want to go to a specific slide by clicking any link from side panel.When I slide up or down there is no scrolling of page, but when I click to go to specific link from panel,the page scrolls down and I can't slide up from that slide.

Is there any way out of showing only the desired slide without scrolling the page and keeping header and panel fixed?
Here is my code-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swiper demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--jquery mobile links -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Demo styles -->
    <style>
    html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;
        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href = "#link1">Slide 1</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#link2">Slide 2</a></li>
            <li><a href = '#link3'>Slide 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="header">
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-grid ui-corner-all"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" id="link1">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" id="link2">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" id = 'link3'>Slide 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.3.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        direction : 'vertical',
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fixed header is probably not be working because your content isn't wrapped inside a JQuery mobile page element. Can you try wrapping your panel, header and swiper divs in a JQuery mobile page e.g. -

```
   <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
               <!--panel content-->
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Fixed header</h1>
            </div>    
            <div role="main">
            <!-- Put your swiper here -->
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Fixed footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

You can check out the JQM documentation on fixed headers here: [JQM Fixed header](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed/)
and fixed panels here: [JQM fixed panels](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-fixed/)